# How do I detect if a player is standing on a certain colour wool?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a map for Minecraft and I want the player to teleport when standing on orange wool. I used this:

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:wool 1 0 tp @p[c=1] 0 0 0
```

But I constantly get an error

> [16:40:51] Failed to execute 'detect' as F1NN3RT

(F1NN3RT is my in-game name)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax of `execute detect` is:

```
/execute <entity> <x> <y> <z> detect <x> <y> <z> <block> <dataValue> <command>
```

You have got an extra 0 after the `dataValue`, which Minecraft thinks is meant to be the command. Try:

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:wool 1 tp @a[c=1] 0 0 0
```

I've also switched the `@p` for an `@a[c=1]`. This is because `@a` will select dead/alive players, but `@p` will not. If a player were to die on orange wool with the original command, they would keep teleporting the nearest alive player to those coordinates.